# duplicate rows in fileds

Tags: text-processing, awk

i have a file like this one

```
    4123    4179    3275    3317
    4137    4193    3331    3373
    4151    4207    3387    3429
                    3443    3485
                    3499    3541
                    3555    3597
```

and i want an idea to how duplicate the $4 and $5 for each value in $1 and $2 so the output will be like this one

```
4123    4179    3275    3317
4123    4179    3331    3373
4123    4179    3387    3429
4123    4179    3443    3485
4123    4179    3499    3541
4123    4179    3555    3597
4137    4193    3275    3317
4137    4193    3331    3373
4137    4193    3387    3429
4137    4193    3443    3485
4137    4193    3499    3541
4137    4193    3555    3597
```

thank you for your time !

Comment: ITYM $3 and $4 rather than $4 and $5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '
    NR==FNR { a[++c,1]=$(NF-1); a[c,2]=$NF; next }
    NF>2 { for (i=1; i<=c; i++) print $1, $2, a[i,1], a[i,2] }
' file file
4123 4179 3275 3317
4123 4179 3331 3373
4123 4179 3387 3429
4123 4179 3443 3485
4123 4179 3499 3541
4123 4179 3555 3597
4137 4193 3275 3317
4137 4193 3331 3373
4137 4193 3387 3429
4137 4193 3443 3485
4137 4193 3499 3541
4137 4193 3555 3597
4151 4207 3275 3317
4151 4207 3331 3373
4151 4207 3387 3429
4151 4207 3443 3485
4151 4207 3499 3541
4151 4207 3555 3597
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash
# generate last two fields file 
# generate first two fields file
# get the number of lines of input

n=$(< file sed -Ene '
  s/\s+/ /g;s/^ | $//g
  s/ /\n/2
  h;s/.*\n//;w f34
  g;s/\n.*//w f12
  $=
')

while IFS= read -r l <&3; do
  yes "$l" | paste -d" " - f34 | head -n "$n" 
done 3< f12
```

**Results**

```
4123 4179 3275 3317
4123 4179 3331 3373
4123 4179 3387 3429
4123 4179 3443 3485
4123 4179 3499 3541
4123 4179 3555 3597
4137 4193 3275 3317
4137 4193 3331 3373
4137 4193 3387 3429
4137 4193 3443 3485
4137 4193 3499 3541
4137 4193 3555 3597
4151 4207 3275 3317
4151 4207 3331 3373
4151 4207 3387 3429
4151 4207 3443 3485
4151 4207 3499 3541
4151 4207 3555 3597
```